# Calculating Strange Union

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Hello everyone assume that we set $A$ = {{1 ,2} , {2 ,3} ,{4 ,3}}

so what is $\cup_{B \in A} (B)$?

Comment: You may be confused by the notation. $\cup_{B\in A} (B)$ means you have to take the union of the elements of $A$, in this case $\cup_{B\in A} (B) = \{1,2\} \cup \{2,3\} \cup \{4,3\}$

Comment: So what is the difference from $\cup{A}$?

Comment: $\cup A$ is a more compact notation for the same thing. It makes sense especially in axiomatic set theory, where everything is a set (including the elements of a set).

Comment: Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

$\{1,2\}\cup \{2,3\} \cup \{4,3\}$..

Comment: So what is the difference from $\cup{A}$?

Comment: Depends on what you want it to stand for. The subscripts are required to avoid confusion: it may very well be $\cup_{A \in \mathcal A} A$. In the absence of a subscript, some authors may say that union is taken over elements of $A$ as in above.

Answer (score 0):

Here The elements of $A$ are $\{1,2\}, \{2,3\}, \{4,3\}$. So the union of elements of $A$ is:

$$\cup_{B\in A} B = \{1,2\} \cup \{2,3\} \cup \{4,3\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

I surmise that this was a trick question.  The intention is for the student to realize that the union of all elements of a specific set is the specific set itself, without any regard to what the elements actually are.

**Addendum**

Subsequent comments by Aurelio and Coward have suggested that I am mistaken.
I may well be mistaken, but I'm just not seeing it yet.

Coward: In response to your comment, could you please provide a counter example?

Aurelio: In response to your counter example, perhaps I'm missing something here.
In your counter example, it does seem to me that $\bigcup_{b \in A} \;=\; A.$
Please explain if you think that I am mistaken.

**Addendum-2**
In response to John Hughes comment below:
Well this is an eye-opener.  His explanation, which never occurred to me, does seem sensible.
I now have to say that (apparently) my knowledge of set theory (re interpretation of notation) is deficient, so my answer (above) may well **be wrong.**

Comment: Are you saying that $\cup A = A$? That's not true.

Comment: I am not convinced by this phrasing. I suppose you mean that the union of a cover of a set is the set itself. For example, for $A=\{\{0\},\{1,2\}\}$, $\cup A\neq A$.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, what you want to say is that a set is the union of its singleton-subsets, which is almost a way of stating the axiom of extensionality.

Comment: @Coward Please see my Addendum.

Comment: Thanks @user2661923 for your remark. In my example above, $\cup A=\{0,1,2\}$. If we disagree, that is probably because we disagree on the meaning of notation, and I am happy to clarify that.

Comment: @Aurelio Please see my Addendum.  I am on shaky ground here.  I don't understand the significance of the phrase "singleton-subsets".  I interpreted the original query to be that B ranged through all of the elements of A, one at a time.  If I am mistaken about this (very possible) please provide a detailed counter example.

Comment: Your answer would be correct if the question had been $\cup_{b \subset A} b$ rather than $\cup_{b \in A} b$. The notation written says to take the union of the *elements* of the set $A$, not its one-element subsets. (My own replacement says to take the union of *all* subsets, not just one-element ones, by the way.)

Comment: @Aurelio I disagree with your interpretation of your own counter-example.  In your counter example, A is a set with exactly two elements.  Each of these elements is itself a set.  One of the elements is a set of one element and the other element (in A) is a set with two elements.  Again, please advise if I am misinterpreting what I thought was standard notation re set theory.

Comment: Let me unpack the notation, always referring to my example. $\cup A=\{0\}\cup\{1,2\}=\{0,1,2\}$. By singleton-subset, I mean a subset which contains a single element - of course this is a definition I would avoid in a foundational setting. But indeed, a set is naively the union of its singleton subsets, that is $A=\{\{0\}\}\cup\{\{1,2\}\}=\{\{0\},\{1,2\}$.

Comment: @user2661923, I believe we are just disagreeing on notation, so not on the underlying maths. The comment by John Hughes above might highlight another possible point of divergence between our interpretations. Indeed, I was referring to singleton-subsets only for the sake of clarity, but we might as well refer to any cover (eg the power-set).

Comment: Apologies for my typo above. It should read $A=\{\{0\}\}\cup\{\{1,2\}\}=\{\{0\},\{1,2\}\}$ (there was a missing brace).